# MobiOne is expired , what should i do to test iphone web page on windows xp . whats the best software about it

Tags: iphone, windows, testing, mobione

i use [MobiOne](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/) to test iphone web page on windows xp

but now  it is expired  ,  i uninstall it, and then reinstall it ,

it is also not running  ,

so what should i do , or whats the best software  about it .

thanks

Comment: Not sure how this relates to programming... seems more like a "hey, whats the best software for <insert here>" question.  Might be more appropriate for http://superuser.com

Comment: What does *is expired* mean in that case?

Comment: @IWasRobbed - I thought that true, but when the `<insert here>` is some form of programming, it's probably here.  The question definitely needs some cleanup and clarification though.

Comment: `MobiOne` is just trial software essentially in this stage of it's deployment.  He's basically saying "I can no longer use this software.  What other software out there exists that does the same thing that can act as a replacement?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking out the latest version of MobiOne that is not expired. As mentioned MobiOne is still in development and old versions expire after a few months to encourage you to try the latest release. The newest version allows you demo your WYSIWYG UI design on your iPhone.